# Tips on writing own CFG

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

Can you give me some tips about writing own grammar given the answer? I mean for example:

> Given 00101, create your own BNF grammar

Comment: As in, you're just trying to express the language `{00101}` in a BNF CFG? What trouble are you having with that example? What's your attempt?

Comment: Here's a tip: if the language is finite, you can write it out as a list of productions, one for each sentence in the language. (The sentence itself is the right-hand side.)